# Length of CDMA code and message length vs. number of participants

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, multiplexing

What is the minimum code size for CDMA codes for **synchronuous CDMA** (not asynchronous CDMA!) with N number of participants?

Furthermore, suppose N parties want to uniquely transmit a message of length K0 each, where K0 is small (e.g. 16 bit) and N is very large (e.g. 1000). What is the minimum size of the total message (i.e., the message including all N different messages of size K0).

Is the minimum size of the transmission K0*N = 16000 bit or can it be made lower?

Comment: I will ask you the same question: do you have any reference for this?

Comment: @blackmath: No I have not of course, otherwise I would not need to ask this question. By the way, the answer “No, this is not possible, for N parties, the code length must be at least N, regardless of the size of N” would be a valid answer as well.

Comment: Because N no of participants can addressed with logN bits ex:-8 people with 3 bits.

Comment: @divB point is that we could infinitely many questions of the scheme "1=2, is this true?", but we don't honor these questions in general, because the effort of asking that question and negatively answering it oneself is way below the effort of answering it as a third party here. So, if you don't have a source, and you don't have a reason to believe this is true, there's not really a question to ask here, to be totally honest.

Comment: @divB I however doubt you don't have a source, because you even use quotation marks in *"with a delicate design of the orthogonal codes"*, so that comes from some *context* that you're omitting here. Please try to add more context! The way it's asked now, you have answered your own question (no, orthogonality isn't possible with less than K dimensions), but I think you're confusing a specific method (orthogonal spreading codes) with the ability to send multiple messages at once.

Comment: @divB Obviously, I meant a source for the quote not the answer. If you don't have a source for the quote, then I regard it as a speculation, and an answer is not in order.

Comment: @Ch.SivaRamKishore: I don't think so because the codes should be orthogonal.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I do not have a reference (I read it somewhere some time ago but forgot where). I have rewritten my question without it.

Comment: @BlackMath: See above, I do not have a reference (don't remember where I read it). I wanted to show that I have put some thoughts into a possible answer rather than asking something that looks like a homework question. However, I rephrased my question completely and hope an answer is not easier.

Comment: "What is the minimum code size for CDMA...", well I guess I could just assign all users a code of length 1 so that would be the minimum code size. Do you want all the users to have orthogonal codes? I'm having a hard time understanding your requirements

Comment: @Engineer If my code is only 1 bit and I have 1000 participants, 500 of them will have the same code and for sure not allow them to uniquely transmit a message. I want all users to have unique codes which allows them to transmit their own messages uniquely (without failure in absence of noise). A unique code per user implies the lower bound of code size log2(N) but this does still not mean each of the N messages can be recovered uniquely. On the other hand I now that a code size of N would be sufficient.

Comment: @divB Yes, I was being a bit silly and as usual it is lost through text...yeah I agree with you that if each user is to have a unique code then the minimum code length is $\text{log}_2(N)$ but as you said these are not orthogonal codes